# pyparsing: grammar for list of Dictionaries (erlang)

Tags: python, parsing, erlang, pyparsing

I'm trying to build a grammar to parse an Erlang tagged tuple list, and map this to a Dict in pyparsing. I'm having problems when I have a list of Dicts. The grammar works if the Dict has just one element, but when I add a second can't work out now to get it to parse.

Current (simplified grammar code (I removed the bits of the language not necessary in this case):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

from pyparsing import *

# Erlang config file definition:
erlangAtom = Word( alphas + '_')
erlangString = dblQuotedString.setParseAction( removeQuotes )

erlangValue = Forward()
erlangList = Forward()

erlangElements = delimitedList( erlangValue )
erlangCSList = Suppress('[') + erlangElements + Suppress(']')
erlangList <<= Group( erlangCSList )
erlangTaggedTuple = Group( Suppress('{') + erlangAtom + Suppress(',') +
                           erlangValue + Suppress('}') )
erlangDict = Dict( Suppress('[') + delimitedList( erlangTaggedTuple ) + 
                   Suppress(']') )

erlangValue <<= ( erlangAtom | erlangString |
                  erlangTaggedTuple |
                  erlangDict | erlangList )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    working = """
[{foo,"bar"}, {baz, "bar2"}]
"""

    broken = """
[
    [{foo,"bar"}, {baz, "bar2"}],
    [{foo,"bob"}, {baz, "fez"}]
]
"""
    w = erlangValue.parseString(working)
    print w.dump()

    b = erlangValue.parseString(broken)
    print "b[0]:", b[0].dump()
    print "b[1]:", b[1].dump()
```

This gives:

```
[['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'bar2']]
- baz: bar2
- foo: bar

b[0]: [['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'bar2'], ['foo', 'bob'], ['baz', 'fez']]
- baz: fez
- foo: bob

b[1]:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./erl_testcase.py", line 39, in <module>
    print "b[1]:", b[1].dump()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 317, in __getitem__
    return self.__toklist[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

i.e. `working` works, but `broken` doesn't parse as two lists.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Tweaked testcase to be more explicit about expected output.

Comment: Can you add the code that actually prints your output?

Comment: I have - see the bottom of the example (print erlangValue.parseString(working).dump())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I have never worked with pyparsing before, so excuse me if my solution does not make sense. Here we go:

As far as I understand what you need is three main structures. The most common mistake you made was grouping delimitedLists. They are already grouped, so you have an issue of double grouping. Here are my definitions:

for {a,"b"}:

```
erlangTaggedTuple = Dict(Group(Suppress('{') + erlangAtom + Suppress(',') + erlangValue + Suppress('}') ))
```

for [{a,"b"}, {c,"d"}]:

```
erlangDict = Suppress('[') + delimitedList( erlangTaggedTuple ) + Suppress(']')
```

for the rest:

```
erlangList <<= Suppress('[') + delimitedList( Group(erlangDict|erlangList) ) + Suppress(']')
```

So my fix for your code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

from pyparsing import *

# Erlang config file definition:
erlangAtom = Word( alphas + '_')
erlangString = dblQuotedString.setParseAction( removeQuotes )

erlangValue = Forward()
erlangList = Forward()

erlangTaggedTuple = Dict(Group(Suppress('{') + erlangAtom + Suppress(',') +
                           erlangValue + Suppress('}') ))
erlangDict = Suppress('[') + delimitedList( erlangTaggedTuple ) + Suppress(']') 
erlangList <<= Suppress('[') + delimitedList( Group(erlangDict|erlangList) ) + Suppress(']')

erlangValue <<= ( erlangAtom | erlangString |
                  erlangTaggedTuple |
                  erlangDict| erlangList )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    working = """
[{foo,"bar"}, {baz, "bar2"}]
"""

    broken = """
[
    [{foo,"bar"}, {baz, "bar2"}],
    [{foo,"bob"}, {baz, "fez"}]
]
"""
    w = erlangValue.parseString(working)
    print w.dump()

    b = erlangValue.parseString(broken)
    print "b[0]:", b[0].dump()
    print "b[1]:", b[1].dump()
```

Which gives the output:

```
[['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'bar2']]
- baz: bar2
- foo: bar
b[0]: [['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'bar2']]
- baz: bar2
- foo: bar
b[1]: [['foo', 'bob'], ['baz', 'fez']]
- baz: fez
- foo: bob
```

Hope that helps, cheers!

Comment: That's great - thanks! All looks good with the small test case; hopefully I can figure out how to expand this up to the full grammar. Bounty well deserved :)

Answer (score 2):

I can't understand why it's not working, because your code looks very much like the [JSON example](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/jsonParser.py/30308858/jsonParser.py), which handles nested lists just fine.

But the problem seems to happen at this line

```
erlangElements = delimitedList( erlangValue )
```

where if the `erlangValue`s are lists, they get appended instead of cons'd. You can kludge around this with

```
erlangElements = delimitedList( Group(erlangValue) )
```

which adds an extra layer of list around the top-most element, but keeps your sub-lists from merging.

Comment: So if I do that then pyparsing does group (and not merge the lists), but the dictionary still doesn't get parsed: `
[[[['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'bar2']], [['foo', 'bob'], ['baz', 'fez']]]]`

Comment: It parses for me. You don't get one dictionary, though. You get a list, containing a list of two dictionaries. So `result[0][0]` and `result[0][1]` are your two dicts. (Are you expecting something else?)

Comment: That might work for me (will have to double-check on the larger grammar) but it adding the extra level of lists means the Erlang data structure doesn't map cleanly to Python, which is problematic. Thing is I don't understand why the current code doesn't work correctly - it already has a Group() in the definition of erlangList...

Comment: So I've gone back to the JSON example but that suffers from exactly the same problem - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081239/pyparsing-example-json-parser-fails-for-list-of-dicts So either we're totally missing something or this is something fundamental in pyparsing...