# pyparsing: example JSON parser fails for list of dicts

Tags: python, json, parsing, pyparsing

All,

I'm trying to understand how to handle a list of Dicts using pyparsing. I've gone back to the [example JSON parser](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/jsonParser.py/30308858/jsonParser.py) for best practices but I've found that it can't handle a list of dicts either!

Consider the following (this is the stock example JSON parser, but with some comments removed and my test case instead of the default one):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

from pyparsing import *

TRUE = Keyword("true").setParseAction( replaceWith(True) )
FALSE = Keyword("false").setParseAction( replaceWith(False) )
NULL = Keyword("null").setParseAction( replaceWith(None) )

jsonString = dblQuotedString.setParseAction( removeQuotes )
jsonNumber = Combine( Optional('-') + ( '0' | Word('123456789',nums) ) +
                    Optional( '.' + Word(nums) ) +
                    Optional( Word('eE',exact=1) + Word(nums+'+-',nums) ) )

jsonObject = Forward()
jsonValue = Forward()
jsonElements = delimitedList( jsonValue )
jsonArray = Group(Suppress('[') + Optional(jsonElements) + Suppress(']') )
jsonValue << ( jsonString | jsonNumber | Group(jsonObject)  | jsonArray | TRUE | FALSE | NULL )
memberDef = Group( jsonString + Suppress(':') + jsonValue )
jsonMembers = delimitedList( memberDef )
jsonObject << Dict( Suppress('{') + Optional(jsonMembers) + Suppress('}') )

jsonComment = cppStyleComment
jsonObject.ignore( jsonComment )

def convertNumbers(s,l,toks):
    n = toks[0]
    try:
        return int(n)
    except ValueError, ve:
        return float(n)

jsonNumber.setParseAction( convertNumbers )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testdata = """
[ { "foo": "bar", "baz": "bar2" },
  { "foo": "bob", "baz": "fez" } ]
    """
    results = jsonValue.parseString(testdata)
    print "[0]:", results[0].dump()
    print "[1]:", results[1].dump()
```

This is valid JSON, but the pyparsing example fails when trying to index into the second expected array element:

```
[0]: [[['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'bar2']], [['foo', 'bob'], ['baz', 'fez']]]
[1]:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json2.py", line 42, in <module>
    print "[1]:", results[1].dump()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 317, in __getitem__
    return self.__toklist[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone help me in identifying what's wrong with this grammar?

**EDIT**: Fixed bug in trying to parse as JSON Object, not value.

*Note: This is related to: [pyparsing: grammar for list of Dictionaries (erlang)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049440/pyparsing-grammar-for-list-of-dictionaries-erlang) where I'm basically trying to do the same with an Erlang data structure, and failing in a similiar way :(*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parse results object that you get back from this expression is a list of the matched tokens - pyparsing doesn't know if you are going to match one or many tokens, so it returns a list, in your case of list containing 1 element, the array of dicts.

Change

```
results = jsonValue.parseString(testdata)
```

to

```
results = jsonValue.parseString(testdata)[0]
```

and I think things will start to look better.  After doing this, I get:

```
[0]: [['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'bar2']]
- baz: bar2
- foo: bar
[1]: [['foo', 'bob'], ['baz', 'fez']]
- baz: fez
- foo: bob
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be [valid JSON](http://json.org/), but your grammar won't handle it. Here's why:

```
jsonObject << Dict( Suppress('{') + Optional(jsonMembers) + Suppress('}') )
```

This says the grammar object **must be surrounded** by `{...}`. You are bracing it as an array `[...]`. Since the top-level object must be a dictionary, it will need key names. Changing your test data to:

```
{ "col1":{ "foo": "bar", "baz": "bar2" },
  "col2":{ "foo": "bob", "baz": "fez" } }
```

or

```
{ "data":[{ "foo": "bar", "baz": "bar2" },
          { "foo": "bob", "baz": "fez" }] }
```

will allow *this grammar* to parse it. Want a top-level object to be an array? Just modify the grammar!

Comment: Thanks for spotting my error trying to parse as an Object instead of a general value, but that still fails to parse in the original form (I can't really change the structure of the JSON. I'd like to modify the grammar to handle the list of dicts but I don't know what's wrong with it!

Comment: @DaveRigby I can't test it right now but it would look something like `jsonObject << Dict( ((Suppress('{') + Optional(jsonMembers) + Suppress('}')) | jsonArray )`

Comment: yep, so I updated the test code above to try to parse as a jsonValue - this does parse without exception, but doesn't give me the correct list of dicts - see above.